# How do I pass a literal value into Jinja2 that is '{{ value }}'

Tags: ansible, jinja2, default, literals

I need to setup a jinja2 template that does this...

```
"message":"{{ policy.message | default('{{message}}') }}"
```

If you don't provide anything to override the message, the json template should take a value of {{message}}.

I've tried a couple of things, but I can't seem to get it to work. It keeps returning this error...

`'message' is undefined`

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

```
"message":"{{ policy.message | default('{{message}}') }}"
```

This line does work. It does add it as needed. The problem I was encountering was a post-verification check to print this render out acted as if there was an undefined var. Essentially it renders the template again. Looks like I just need to make that a literal print instead of render and that fixes my problem. Thanks all.

Comment: why answering a question that already have many answers with a very hi score if you cannot provide something better ? Plz follow SO policy.